# Set DOM element's attribute whose name does not match XML's Name production

Tags: javascript, html, dom, attributes

I have an HTML element.

I can read the value of one of its attributes using [`getAttribute`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-element-getattribute).

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('div').getAttribute('~')); // "123"
```

```html
<div class="test" ~="123"></div>
```

However, I can't use [`setAttribute`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-element-setattribute) if the attribute name does not match the [`Name`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Name) production in XML. It throws an "[`InvalidCharacterError`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#invalidcharactererror)" exception.

```js
var el = document.querySelector('div');
el.setAttribute('~', '123'); // InvalidCharacterError
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

[`setAttributeNS`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-element-setattributens) behaves the same. [`createAttribute`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1084891198) and [`createAttributeNS`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-DocCrAttrNS) have been removed, and they behaved the same.

Then, given that I can bypass this restriction in HTML, is there a way to bypass it in DOM?

Replacing the subtree with a deserialization of a modified HTML serialization is not an option. I don't want to destroy internal data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1. Use `innerHTML` to parse a HTML string with an element with the desired attribute name.
2. Remove the attribute from that element (attributes can belong only to a single element).
3. Change the value of the attribute to the desired value.
4. Set the attribute to the desired element.

```js
function setAttr(el, name, value) {
  if(/[\u0000\u0009\u000A\u000C\u000D\u0020\u002F\u003D\u003E]/.test(name))
    throw new Error('InvalidCharacterError');
  var htmlString = '<br ' + name + ' />';
  var parser = document.createElement('div');
  parser.innerHTML = htmlString;
  var attrs = parser.firstChild.attributes;
  if(attrs.length !== 1 || attrs.item(0).name !== name) // Just to be safe
    throw new Error('InvalidCharacterError'); // This should not happen
  var attr = attrs.removeNamedItem(name);
  attr.value = value;
  el.attributes.setNamedItem(attr);
}
var el = document.querySelector('div');
setAttr(el, '~', '123');
console.log(el.getAttribute('~')); // "123"
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Of course, even the HTML parser is not capable of creating arbitrary attributes. For example, they can't contain spaces.